# json refresh no ajax ,websockets

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, websocket

I want to get the data from here

https://btc-e.com/api/3/ticker/btc_usd

in php i use :

```
$jsonbtce    = file_get_contents('https://btc-e.com/api/3/ticker/btc_usd');
$decodedbtce = json_decode($jsonbtce);
$lastprice    = $decodedbtce->btc_usd->last;
```

then i use jquery ajax to refresh the data

```
var updateInterval = setInterval(function() {
 $('.mydivclass').load('btce.php');
},3*1000);
```

How can i use **websockets** with jquery or javascript to get the data from that url ? so i can use the $lastprice for other stuff even if price updates,**using ajax not good.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem as you. I'm sorry to say that you will need to set up a WebSocket server (written in PHP or Java, for example) and configure it. Take a look at `Ratchet ws server`, `node.js webSocket servers` or search through `GitHub` for a webSocket server.

This is the info I have.
I will be glad if someone posts a more specific answer.
[This](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/12/websockets-an-introduction/) looks very nice, if you know Java.